# How to return a partial view from JIRA plugin WebWork action or command?

Tags: view, velocity, partial, jira-plugin

I have some parts of my plugin which are loaded through AJAX on demand. Now there is a problem that although my velocity template for that command does not contain html head nor body tags, still JIRA inserts them automatically when I request my view from `http://localhost:2990/jira/secure/MyAction!myCommand.jspa`

How do I return only HTML structure from my own Velocity .vm view and stop JIRA from injecting its headers and body?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness (if other users find this question): The answer is to wrap your template in a html body with the following header meta tag:

```
<meta name="decorator" content="none">
```

Additional information can be found under the [same topic on Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/240003/how-to-return-a-partial-view-from-webwork-action-or-command).

The reason why a simple query parameter (*?...&decorator=none...*) has stopped working in Confluence 5 is documented in [JIRA](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-20865).